# Why I am getting only Ok as answer from the sim800l module?

Tags: at-command

I'm trying to communicate with the sim800l gprs module. When I send AT to the module, it answers with OK. Then if I try another command, as ATI, it only answers me with OK. It doesn't matters wich command I send to it, I always get a OK:

> AT
>
> OK AT
>
> OK I AT E0
>
> OK AT I\ r\
>
> OK n

As you can see, the commands sent were AT, ATI, ATE0, ATI\r\n, but the only answer I got was OK.

What should I do to get it working properly?
Thanks

Comment: Could you include the code you use for sending AT commands. Does the same result occur when running the commands in a terminal program?

Comment: No response from the OP in 4.5years, with some information missing. This question has no chance to receive an answer.